# Need help stubbing async / await promise with Sinon in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, mocha.js, sinon

I have two functions called in my controller that return a promise, when I run my test it fails with `expected stub to be called once but was called 0 times.` however if I remove those promise functions from the controller it works fine.

**FileTransferController.js**

```
const { getIncomingFiles, getOutgoingFiles } = require('../services')

const controller = {}

controller.getFileTransfers = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const incoming = await getIncomingFiles()
    const outgoing = await getOutgoingFiles()
    return res.status(200).send({ incoming, outgoing })
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err)
  }
}

module.exports = controller
```

**FileTransferService.js**

```
const service = {}

const { Job } = require('../models')

service.getIncomingFiles = () => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    const jobs = await Job.findAll({
      where: {
        job_name: 'Some Job Name',
      },
    })
    resolve(jobs)
  } catch (err) {
    reject(err)
  }
})

service.getOutgoingFiles = () => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    const jobs = await Job.findAll({
      where: {
        job_name: 'Some Job Name',
      },
    })
    resolve(jobs)
  } catch (err) {
    reject(err)
  }
})

module.exports = service
```

Here is my unit test. I've tried this 10 different ways based on what I have read from other similar stack overflow questions but nothing seems to work. I feel like what I currently have is the closest.

**My Unit Test**

```
const sinon = require('sinon')
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire')

let sandbox
let FileTransferController
let FileTransferService

beforeEach(() => {
  sandbox = sinon.createSandbox()
  FileTransferService = {
    getIncomingFiles: sandbox.stub().resolves([]),
    getOutgoingFiles: sandbox.stub().resolves([]),
  }

  FileTransferController = proxyquire('../../../src/controllers/FileTransferController', {
    '../services': FileTransferService,
  })
})
afterEach(() => {
  sandbox.restore()
})

describe('FileTransferController.js', () => {
  describe('getFileTransfers()', () => {
    let req
    let res
    beforeEach(() => {
      req = {}
      res = {
        send: sandbox.stub(),
        status: sandbox.stub().returns,
      }
      FileTransferController.getFileTransfers(req, res)
    })
    it('should only call send once', () => {
      sinon.assert.calledOnce(res.send)
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue. Instead of trying to stub the service functions I needed to proxyquire the service and stub the sequelize models promise functions.

```
const sinon = require('sinon')
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire')
const { Job } = require('../../../src/models')


let req
let res
let sandbox

before(() => {
  sandbox = sinon.createSandbox()
  req = {}
  res = {
    send: sandbox.stub(),
    status: sandbox.stub().returns,
  }
})
after(() => {
  sandbox.restore()
})

describe('FileTransferController.js', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    sandbox.stub(Job, 'findAll').resolves({})
    const FileTransferService = proxyquire('../../../src/services/FileTransferService', {
      Job,
    })
    const FileTransferController = proxyquire('../../../src/controllers/FileTransferController', {
      '../services/FileTransferService': FileTransferService,
    })
    await FileTransferController.getFileTransfers(req, res)
  })
  afterEach(() => {
    Job.findAll.restore()
  })
  describe('getFileTransfers()', () => {
    it('should only call send once', () => {
      sinon.assert.calledOnce(res.send)
    })
  })
})
```